# Making only the graphic inside the bounds of a sprite draggable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, draggable

I'm building a game upon which objects can be dragged around and arranged to build different types of animals. My question is, is there a way to define the draggable area of each sprite beyond just a simple rectangle? Many of the graphics in my sprites are elliptical and triangular in nature which leaves a lot of clear space around the actual image. I'd like to make just the graphic within the rectangular bounds of my sprite draggable. How can this be done?

Here are some of the graphics to illustrate what I mean by irregular shapes.

[image]

So when you draw a bounding box around these shapes there is a lot of clear space that I don't want to be draggable or clickable. I already have a script that handles dragging, but it makes the entire sprite draggable, how do I make just the 2D Polygon Collider accept the drag event?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DragHandling : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    Vector3 partsPanelScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    public float partScale;
    // public float partRotate;
    Vector3 buildPanelScale;
    // Vector3 buildPanelRotate;

    [HideInInspector] public Transform placeholderParent = null;
    [HideInInspector] public Transform parentToReturnTo = null;

    GameObject placeholder = null;

    [HideInInspector] public GameObject animalPart;

    [HideInInspector] public GameObject trashCan; 
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject partsPanel;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject partsWindow;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject buildBoard;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject horns;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject heads;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject ears;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject necks;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject bodies;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject legs;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject tails;
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject more;

    GameObject dragLayer;

    void Start ()
    {
        dragLayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DragLayer");
        buildBoard = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board");
        partsPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Parts");
        partsWindow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PartsWindow");
        trashCan = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Trash");

        horns = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Horns");
        heads = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Heads");
        ears = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Ears");
        necks = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Necks");
        bodies = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Bodies");
        legs = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Legs");
        tails = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-Tails");
        more = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AnimalPart-More");
    }

    #region IPointerClickHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
        {
            transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IBeginDragHandler implementation

    public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // create placeholder gap and hold correct position in layout
        placeholder = new GameObject();
        placeholder.transform.SetParent(transform.parent);
        placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(transform.GetSiblingIndex());
/*
        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
        {
            partsPanelScale = transform.localScale;
        }
*/
        parentToReturnTo = transform.parent;                                    // store current parent location
        placeholderParent = parentToReturnTo;                                   // set placeholder gameobject transform

        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;                     // turn off image raycasting when dragging image in order to see what's behind the image            
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDragHandler implementation

    float distance = 0;

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, distance);
        // Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ViewportToScreenPoint(mousePosition);
        transform.position = mousePosition;                                 // set object coordinates to mouse coordinates

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
        {
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);                           // pop object to draglayer to move object out of parts Panel
        }

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
        {
            transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);
            // Constrain drag to boundaries of buildBoard Code
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEndDragHandler implementation

    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.SetParent(parentToReturnTo);                                  // Snaps object back to orginal parent if dropped outside of a dropzone
        transform.SetSiblingIndex(placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex());     // Returns card back to placeholder location

        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;                      // turn Raycast back on
        Destroy(placeholder);                                                   // kill the placeholder if object hits a drop zone or returns to parts panel

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
        {
            // Debug.Log ("Your sprite is now on the " + transform.parent.name);

            buildPanelScale = new Vector3(partScale, partScale, partScale);
            transform.localScale = buildPanelScale;
            transform.SetAsLastSibling();                                       
        }

        if(transform.parent.gameObject == partsPanel)
        {
            // transform.SetParent(buildBoard.transform);
            transform.localScale = partsPanelScale;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "interaction area"?

Comment: He probably means the collider

Comment: What I mean is when I create sprites they always have rectangular bounds, but I don't want the entire sprite to be draggable, only the graphic within the bounds. Is there a way to do that with a collider?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a BoxCollider2D as the default colliderfor your puzzle pieces, you could change that out to [PolygonCollider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html) instead. It automatically generates the collider for your Sprite (IIRC, it uses the alpha channel), and you can also further customize it by adding vertices to the collider's mesh.

Comment: Okay, cool. So I drew a Polygon collider that outlines just the graphic area within the bounds of my sprite, but how do I then make just that collider area draggable?

Comment: Make a script that uses OnMouseDrag, and write your code there

Comment: I already have a script that handles dragging (posted above), but it makes the entire sprite draggable, how do I make just the 2D Polygon Collider accept the drag event?